# Angles of triangles of a 3D mesh using #CGAL

Tags: mesh, cgal

I would like to know if it is possible to compute the angles of triangles of a 3D mesh (represented with a graph) using a function of CGAL ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to compute the angles in a triangle, or compute statistics on the angles of the triangles?

Comment: I want to compute angles in triangles

Comment: In 2D or 3D? The answer will be different. Please modify your question post using the "edit" button below it.

Comment: ok i made the changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a non-degenerated triangle with three points `a`, `b`, and `c`, the angle of triangle, the cosine of the angle at `a` is the scalar product of two vectors divided by their lengths:

```
CGAL::Vector_3<K> v1 = b - a;
CGAL::Vector_3<K> v2 = c - a;
double cosine = v1 * v2 / CGAL::sqrt(v1*v1) / CGAL::sqrt(v2 * v2);
```

where `K` is the type of kernel that you are using for the points. The angle itself *in radius* can be computed by:

```
double angle = std::acos(cosine);
```

Of course, for degenerate triangles, the lengths can be zero, and the expression above will compute `0./0.` (that is a *not-a-number*). You have to deal with that case separately.