# Angles of triangles of a 2D mesh using #CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

There is already an answer for this question but for a 2D mesh:
[Angles of triangles of a 3D mesh using #CGAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435384/angles-of-triangles-of-a-3d-mesh-using-cgal)

I understand that the answer is different regarding 2D. So: how to compute the angles of triangles of a 2D mesh in CGAL? I can take the vertices and their respective Vector by making pairs, but I'm looking for a straight forward way of calculating the angles, without making a check if it's the outer or the inner angle.

If it makes any difference, this mesh has been produced by a CDT.

Answer (score 0):

It was simple alright, but I thought it might help someone, since a comment by Laurent Rineauin in the initial 3D mesh question, proposed that the solution is different. So here it is:

```
// faces_iterator iterates through the triangles of l_cdt CDT triangulation

CGAL::Point_2<K> vertex1 = l_cdt.triangle(faces_iterator)[0];
CGAL::Point_2<K> vertex2 = l_cdt.triangle(faces_iterator)[1];
CGAL::Point_2<K> vertex3 = l_cdt.triangle(faces_iterator)[2];

double a = CGAL::sqrt((vertex2.x() - vertex3.x()) * (vertex2.x() - vertex3.x()) + (vertex2.y() - vertex3.y()) * (vertex2.y() - vertex3.y()));
double b = CGAL::sqrt((vertex1.x() - vertex3.x()) * (vertex1.x() - vertex3.x()) + (vertex1.y() - vertex3.y()) * (vertex1.y() - vertex3.y()));
double c = CGAL::sqrt((vertex2.x() - vertex1.x()) * (vertex2.x() - vertex1.x()) + (vertex2.y() - vertex1.y()) * (vertex2.y() - vertex1.y()));

// constants::PI is just π, for conversion to degrees instead of radians 
double angle1 = ((std::acos((b*b + c*c - a*a) / (2*b*c))) * 180) / constants::PI;
double angle2 = ((std::acos((a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c))) * 180) / constants::PI;
double angle3 = ((std::acos((a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2*b*a))) * 180) / constants::PI;
```

Comment: I believe you can use `CGAL::squared_distance` to compute a, b and c.